# How to define correct GAE endpoint scope

Tags: google-app-engine

In Google App Engine GAE1, I has a REST API implemented in Tastypie:

(pseudo API)
https://mygae.google.com/api_rest/api/v1/myapi/?format=json (works if accessing from browser)

The following code is to access GAE1 REST API from another GAE2 through OAuth2, key.p12 is created from GAE console.

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

f = file('~/key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
      'xxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
      key,
      scope='https://mygae.google.com/api_rest/api/')

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

API_ROOT = 'https://mygae.google.com/'
DISCOVERY_URL = API_ROOT + '/api_rest/api/{apiVersion}/{api}/?format=json'

#### Invalid scope ERROR will happen here.
service = build("myapi", "v1", http=http,
                discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URL)

lists = service.tasklist
pprint.pprint(lists)
```

But, it has invalid scope error:

----- Error message ----

oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope: scope='https://mygae.google.com/api_rest/api/ is not valid scope.

How to define correct scope in this case? Is OAuth2 working for this case? Is this right way to access GAE1 API? If not, how to access GAE 1 API? Please provide sample code.

As you can see, I am really confused by "scope". Scope is google API or the API I created? What is relationship between scope and the discovery URL?